# JOIN queries vs multiple queries

Tags: mysql, database, join, query-optimization

Are JOIN queries faster than several queries? (You run your main query, and then you run many other SELECTs based on the results from your main query)

I'm asking because JOINing them would complicate A LOT the design of my application

If they are faster, can anyone approximate very roughly by how much? If it's 1.5x I don't care, but if it's 10x I guess I do.

Comment: I'm assume they would be faster. I know that one INSERT compared to say 10 individual INSERT queries is much faster.

Comment: It might be important whether your multiple queries are inside a stored procedure of if they originate from the application (edit your question with this info).  The former will be much quicker than the later.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/are-individual-queries-faster-than-joins

Comment: I have a problem where the join is much slower than the sum of the time required for the individual queries, despite primary key. I am guessing that SQLITE is trying to save time by going through the rows and checking for the queried values instead of performing the query multiple times. But this is not working well in many cases if you have a fast index on that particular column.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is way too vague to give you an answer relevant to your specific case. It depends on a lot of things. Jeff Atwood (founder of this site) actually [wrote about this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/all-abstractions-are-failed-abstractions.html). For the most part, though, if you have the right indexes and you properly do your JOINs it is usually going to be faster to do 1 trip than several.

Comment: if you are joining 3 or more tables on different keys, often databases (i.e. mysql) can only use one index per table, meaning maybe one of the joins will be fast (and use an index) whereas the others will be extremely slow. For multiple queries, you can optimize the indexes to use for each query.

Comment: I think this depends on your definition of "faster" ... for example, 3 PK inner joins may turn around faster than 4 round-trips, because of network overhead, and because you need to stop and prepare and send each query after the previous query completes. If you were to benchmark a server under load, however, in most cases, joins will take more CPU time vs PK queries, and often causes more network overhead as well.

Comment: Why would you have to do more than 1 round-trip? I think it should also be possible to run multiple queries and fetch the resulting sets at once.

Answer (score 143):

For inner joins, a single query makes sense, since you only get matching rows.
For left joins, multiple queries is much better... look at the following benchmark I did:

1. **Single query with 5 Joins**

   query: **8.074508 seconds**

   result size: 2268000
2. **5 queries in a row**

   combined query time: **0.00262 seconds**

   result size: 165 (6 + 50 + 7 + 12 + 90)

.

Note that we get the same results in both cases (6 x 50 x 7 x 12 x 90 = 2268000)

left joins use exponentially more memory with redundant data.

The memory limit might not be as bad if you only do a join of two tables, but generally three or more and it becomes worth different queries.

As a side note, my MySQL server is right beside my application server... so connection time is negligible. If your connection time is in the seconds, then maybe there is a benefit

Frank

Comment: If we toss aside the annoying little fact that nobody in their right mind does a cross join between 5 tables (for that very reason, along with that in most cases it *just doesn't make sense*), your "benchmark" might have some merit.  But left or inner joins are the norm, usually by key (making retrieval much faster), and the duplication of data is usually much, *much* less than you're making it out to be.

Comment: @cHao says who? I just looked up SMF and phpBB and saw JOINs between 3 tables - if you add plugins or modifications they could easily add to that. Any sort of large application has the potential for many JOINs. Arguably a poorly written/mis-used ORM could JOIN tables that it doesn't actually need (perhaps even every table).

Comment: @NathanAdams: Left and inner joins aren't bad at all.  (In fact, if you're not joining tables here and there, you're doing SQL wrong.)  What i was talking about is *cross joins*, which are almost always undesirable even between two tables, let alone 5 -- and which would be about the only way to get the otherwise-totally-bogus "2268000" results mentioned above.

Comment: Look at the results, though.  "result size: 2268000" versus "result size: 165".  I think your slowdown with JOINs is because your records have a one-to-many relationship with each other, whereas if they had a one-to-one relationship, the JOIN would absolutely be much faster and it certainly wouldn't have a result size bigger than the SELECT.

Comment: @cHao Obviously you have not met Magento at the time of your first comment

Comment: @vitoriodachef: Still haven't, actually. But I stand by the comment. A cross join implies that every possible pairing of rows makes sense -- which is rare enough between *two* tables that I've never wanted to do it. There is a way of writing queries so that they *look* like a cross join when they're actually inner joins, but the DB knows better as long as you have unique indexes or primary keys. (And if Magento has survived this long, then its DB schema is such that you will *never* have reason to do a cross join between five tables.)

Comment: This answer is not specific enough and probably generalizes some corner case: Were indices used? What was the cardinality of the data?

Comment: "For inner joins, a single query makes sense, since you only get matching rows." that is **WAY** too general of an answer, and it's just plain wrong in many cases. Here's a good example: let's say I have a table called `Event` and I'm trying to join `Ticket`s. There could be thousands of `Ticket`s per `Event`; even if we assume some `Event`s don't have tickets and left joined, the bigger performance hit would obviously be from the massive number of matching rows, not the few misses.

Answer (score 72):

This question is old, but is missing some benchmarks. I benchmarked JOIN against its 2 competitors:

- N+1 queries
- 2 queries, the second one using a `WHERE IN(...)` or equivalent

The result is clear: on MySQL, `JOIN` is *much* faster. N+1 queries can drop the performance of an application drastically:

[image: JOIN vs WHERE IN vs N+1]

That is, unless you select a lot of records that point to a very small number of distinct, foreign records. Here is a benchmark for the extreme case:

[image: JOIN vs N+1 - all records pointing to the same foreign record]

This is very unlikely to happen in a typical application, unless you're joining a -to-many relationship, in which case the foreign key is on the other table, and you're duplicating the main table data many times.

Takeaway:

- For *-to-one relationships, always use `JOIN`
- For *-to-many relationships, a second query *might* be faster

See [my article on Medium](https://medium.com/@benmorel/to-join-or-not-to-join-bba9c1377c10) for more information.

Answer (score 26):

I actually came to this question looking for an answer myself, and after reading the given answers I can only agree that the best way to compare DB queries performance is to get real-world numbers because there are just to many variables to be taken into account BUT, I also think that comparing the numbers between them leads to no good in almost all cases. What I mean is that the numbers should always be compared with an acceptable number and definitely not compared with each other.

I can understand if one way of querying takes say 0.02 seconds and the other one takes 20 seconds, that's an enormous difference. But what if one way of querying takes 0.0000000002 seconds, and the other one takes 0.0000002 seconds ? In both cases one way is a whopping 1000 times faster than the other one, but is it **really** still "whopping" in the second case ?

Bottom line as I personally see it: if it performs well, go for the easy solution.

Comment: That, of course, depending on whether or not you're planning on scaling. Cuz when facebook started out I'm sure they had those kind of queries, but had scaling in mind and went for the more efficient albeit possibly more complex solution.

Comment: @dudewad Makes sense. It all depends on what you need, in the end.

Comment: Haha yeah... because at google 1 nanosecond lost is literally equal to something like 10 billion trillion dollars... but that's just a rumor.

Comment: @dudewad Actually, when Facebook started out, I guarantee they went with the simpler solution. Zuckerberg said he programmed the first version in only 2 weeks. Start ups need to move _fast_ to compete and the ones that survive usually don't worry about scaling until they actually need it. _Then_ they refactor stuff after they have millions of investment dollars and can hire rockstar programmers that specialize in performance. To your point, I would expect Facebook often goes for the more complex solution for minute performance gains now, but then most of us aren't programming Facebook.

Answer (score 22):

The real question is: *Do these records have a **one-to-one relationship** or a **one-to-many relationship**?*

**TLDR Answer:**

If one-to-one, use a `JOIN` statement.

If one-to-many, use one (or many) `SELECT` statements with server-side code optimization.

**Why and How To Use SELECT for Optimization**

`SELECT`'ing (with multiple queries instead of joins) on large group of records based on a one-to-many relationship produces an optimal efficiency, as `JOIN`'ing has an exponential memory leak issue.  Grab all of the data, then use a server-side scripting language to sort it out:

```
SELECT * FROM Address WHERE Personid IN(1,2,3);
```

Results:

```
Address.id : 1            // First person and their address
Address.Personid : 1
Address.City : "Boston"

Address.id : 2            // First person's second address
Address.Personid : 1
Address.City : "New York"

Address.id : 3            // Second person's address
Address.Personid : 2
Address.City : "Barcelona"
```

Here, I am getting all of the records, in one select statement.  This is better than `JOIN`, which would be getting a small group of these records, one at a time, as a sub-component of another query.  Then I parse it with server-side code that looks something like...

```
<?php
    foreach($addresses as $address) {
         $persons[$address['Personid']]->Address[] = $address;
    }
?>
```

**When Not To Use JOIN for Optimization**

`JOIN`'ing a large group of records based on a one-to-one relationship with one single record produces an optimal efficiency compared to multiple `SELECT` statements, one after the other, which simply get the next record type.

But `JOIN` is inefficient when getting records with a one-to-many relationship.

Example: The database Blogs has 3 tables of interest, Blogpost, Tag, and Comment.

```
SELECT * from BlogPost
LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.BlogPostid = BlogPost.id
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.BlogPostid = BlogPost.id;
```

If there is 1 blogpost, 2 tags, and 2 comments, you will get results like:

```
Row1: tag1, comment1,
Row2: tag1, comment2,
Row3: tag2, comment1,
Row4: tag2, comment2,
```

Notice how each record is duplicated.  Okay, so, 2 comments and 2 tags is 4 rows.  What if we have 4 comments and 4 tags?  You don't get 8 rows -- you get 16 rows:

```
Row1: tag1, comment1,
Row2: tag1, comment2,
Row3: tag1, comment3,
Row4: tag1, comment4,
Row5: tag2, comment1,
Row6: tag2, comment2,
Row7: tag2, comment3,
Row8: tag2, comment4,
Row9: tag3, comment1,
Row10: tag3, comment2,
Row11: tag3, comment3,
Row12: tag3, comment4,
Row13: tag4, comment1,
Row14: tag4, comment2,
Row15: tag4, comment3,
Row16: tag4, comment4,
```

Add more tables, more records, etc., and the problem will quickly inflate to hundreds of rows that are all full of *mostly* redundant data.

What do these duplicates cost you?  Memory (in the SQL server and the code that tries to remove the duplicates) and networking resources (between SQL server and your code server).

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html ; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html

Comment: You miss the point. It's not about one-to-(one|many). It's about whether the sets of rows make sense being paired together. You're asking for two only tangentially related sets of data. If you were asking for comments and, say, their authors' contact info, that makes more sense as a join, even though people can presumably write more than one comment.

Comment: @cHao: Thanks for your comment.  My answer above is a summary of the MySQL Documentation found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html

Comment: That's not MySQL documentation. It's documentation for a particular GUI tool for working with MySQL databases. And it doesn't offer any guidance on when joins are (or are not) appropriate.

Comment: @cHao: Sorry, I meant the MySQL (R) documentation for MySQL WorkBench (TM), not MySQL Server (TM).

Comment: Pedantry aside, the relevance isn't clear. Both mention one-to-one and one-to-many relationships, but that's where the commonality ends. Either way, the issue is about the relationship between the sets of data. Join two unrelated sets, you're going to get every combination of the two. Break related data up into multiple selects, and now you've done multiple queries for dubious benefit, and started doing MySQL's job for it.

Comment: @cHao: I didn't even really add anything much in my last comment (I imagine we agree on this), but you still seem to have a lot more to say.  Maybe you should post your own answer?  Comments have a character limit for good reason.

Comment: "It's about whether the sets of rows make sense being paired together": no, the question is about performance.

Comment: I want to point out that the problem is even mathematically MORE significant than this answer indicates.  @HoldOffHunger points out you're getting 16 rows instead of 8.  That's one way of looking at it.  But really if you look at the data redundancy, you're getting 32 data points instead of 8.  Its already 4x data for just 2 joins!!!!!  If you add just one more join to make 3, it will get absolutely ridiculoussssss!

Comment: If you join a 3rd column that returned 4 additional records for each of the pairs already demonstrated by @HoldOffHunger, you would technically only have 12 meaningful data points, BUT you would have 64 rows and 192 data points.

Comment: One more thing worth pointing out:  More memory = slower performance.  Memory is enormously slow compared to processor cycles on cache data.  Anything that makes an application have to churn more memory will also make it actually process slower.

Comment: Dammit you were so close... Yes, 1-1 almost always means join. But I could easily make a case for a 1-M join if the number of entities on the many side related to a single entity is small enough on average to be worth it.

Answer (score 16):

Did a quick test selecting one row from a 50,000 row table and joining with one row from a 100,000 row table. Basically looked like:

```
$id = mt_rand(1, 50000);
$row = $db->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = " . $id);
$row = $db->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE other_id = " . $row['other_id']);
```

vs

```
$id = mt_rand(1, 50000);
$db->fetchOne("SELECT table1.*, table2.*
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table1.other_id = table2.other_id
    WHERE table1.id = " . $id);
```

The two select method took 3.7 seconds for 50,000 reads whereas the JOIN took 2.0 seconds on my at-home slow computer. INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN did not make a difference. Fetching multiple rows (e.g., using IN SET) yielded similar results.

Comment: Maybe the difference might turn otherwise if selecting a page of rows (like 20 or 50) as if for a typical web view grid, and comparing single LEFT JOIN to two queries - selecting 2 or 3 identifiers with some WHERE criteria and then running the other SELECT query with IN().

Comment: Are the columns id and other_id indexed ?

Answer (score 8):

Construct both separate queries and joins, then time each of them -- nothing helps more than real-world numbers.

Then even better -- add "EXPLAIN" to the beginning of each query. This will tell you how many subqueries MySQL is using to answer your request for data, and how many rows scanned for each query.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the complexity for the database compared to developer complexity, it may be simpler to do many SELECT calls.

Try running some database statistics against both the JOIN and the multiple SELECTS. See if in your environment the JOIN is faster/slower than the SELECT.

Then again, if changing it to a JOIN would mean an extra day/week/month of dev work, I'd stick with multiple SELECTs

Cheers,

BLT

Answer (score 7):

In my experience I have found it's usually faster to run several queries, especially when retrieving large data sets.

When interacting with the database from another application, such as PHP, there is the argument of one trip to the server over many.

There are other ways to limit the number of trips made to the server and still run multiple queries that are often not only faster but also make the application easier to read - for example mysqli_multi_query.

I'm no novice when it comes to SQL, I think there is a tendency for developers, especially juniors to spend a lot of time trying to write very clever joins because they look smart, whereas there are actually smart ways to extract data that look simple.

The last paragraph was a personal opinion, but I hope this helps. I do agree with the others though who say you should benchmark. Neither approach is a silver bullet.

Comment: Yes, we should also account not only for queries themselves but also for data processing inside the application. If fetching data with outer joins, there is some redundancy (sometimes it can get really huge) which has to be sorted out by the app (usually in some ORM library), thus in summary the single SELECT with JOIN query might consume more CPU and time than two simple SELECTs

Answer (score 6):

Will it be faster in terms of throughput? Probably. But it also potentially locks more database objects at a time (depending on your database and your schema) and thereby decreases concurrency. In my experience people are often mislead by the "fewer database round-trips" argument when in reality on most OLTP systems where the database is on the same LAN, the real bottleneck is rarely the network.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you should use a join is first and foremost about whether a join *makes sense*. Only at that point is performance even something to be considered, as nearly all other cases will result in significantly *worse* performance.

Performance differences will largely be tied to how related the info you're querying for is. Joins work, and they're fast when *the data is related* and you index stuff correctly, but they do often result in some redundancy and sometimes more results than needed. And if your data sets are not directly related, sticking them in a single query will result in what's called a Cartesian product (basically, all possible combinations of rows), which is almost never what you want.

This is often caused by many-to-one-to-many relationships. For example, [HoldOffHunger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144454/319403) mentioned a single query for posts, tags, and comments. Comments are related to a post, as are tags...but tags are unrelated to comments.

```
+------------+     +---------+     +---------+
|  comment   |     |   post  |     |  tag    |
|------------|*   1|---------|1   *|---------|
| post_id    |-----| post_id |-----| post_id |
| comment_id |     | ...     |     | tag_id  |
| user_id    |     |         |     | ...     |
| ...        |     |         |     | ...     |
+------------+     +---------+     +---------+
```

In this case, it is unambiguously better for this to be at least two separate queries. If you try to join tags and comments, because there's no direct relation between the two, you end up with every possible combination of tag and comment. `many * many == manymany`. Aside from that, since comments and tags are unrelated, you can do those two queries in parallel, leading to potential gain.

Let's consider a different scenario, though: You want the comments attached to a post, and the commenters' contact info.

```
 +----------+     +------------+     +---------+
 |   user   |     |  comment   |     |   post  |
 |----------|1   *|------------|*   1|---------|
 | user_id  |-----| post_id    |-----| post_id |
 | username |     | user_id    |     | ...     |
 | ...      |     | ...        |     +---------+
 +----------+     +------------+
```

This is where you should consider a join. Aside from being a much more natural query, most database systems (including MySQL) have lots of smart people put lots of hard work into optimizing queries just like it. For separate queries, since each query depends on the results of the previous one, the queries can't be done in parallel, and the total time becomes not just the actual execute time of the queries, but also the time spent fetching results, sifting through them for IDs for the next query, linking rows together, etc.

Comment: If you retrieve a lot of user columns in the second scenario (and the same users comment more than once), this still leaves open the question as to whether they are best retrieved in a separate query.

Comment: @AdrianBaker: Like i said, lots of smart people putting lots of hard work in.  If i were going to optimize my SQL server, my very first idea would be to use compression, which would eliminate a huge amount of redundancy without changing the code much at all. Next-level optimizations would include reorganizing the result into tables and sending those along with tuples of row ids, which the client library could then easily assemble on its side as needed.

Comment: Both of those optimizations could work wonders with a join to reduce or even eliminate the redundancy, but there's not much that can help with the inherently serial queries you'd have to do to fetch related records.

Comment: How would a `comment join tag on comment.post_id = tag.post_id` be different from `post join tag on post.post_id = tag.post_id`? In both cases you'd have a `comment`/`post` row duplicated for each tag that relates to the relevant `post_id`. And it wouldn't be all possible combinations: a `comment` with `post_id = 5` won't be paired with `tag` with `post_id = 20`. Isn't the issue in the nature of the relationship - being `Many` at least on one side, rather than `One` on both? But that's not the issue of `tag` and `comment` not having a 'direct relationship'?

Comment: @parsecer: `comment join tag` gives you a row for every combination of tag and comment that relate to a post.  If you have a post with thousand comments and 20 tags, `comment join tag` nets you 20000 rows for that post, rather than the 1020 you'd get from two queries.

Comment: @parsecer: Those 20000 rows would include 20 copies of each comment and a thousand duplicates of each tag, so you'd have to do postprocessing just to make sense of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link with 100 useful queries, these are tested in Oracle database but remember SQL is a standard, what differ between Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL and other databases are the SQL dialect:

http://javaforlearn.com/100-sql-queries-learn/

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors which means there is no binary answer.  The question of what is best for performance depends on your environment.  By the way, if your single select with an identifier is not sub-second, something may be wrong with your configuration.

The real question to ask is how do you want to access the data.  Single selects support late-binding.  For example if you only want employee information, you can select from the Employees table.  The foreign key relationships can be used to retrieve related resources at a later time and as needed.  The selects will already have a key to point to so they should be extremely fast, and you only have to retrieve what you need.  Network latency must always be taken into account.

Joins will retrieve all of the data at once.  If you are generating a report or populating a grid, this may be exactly what you want.  Compiled and optomized joins are simply going to be faster than single selects in this scenario.  Remember, Ad-hoc joins may not be as fast--you should compile them (into a stored proc).  The speed answer depends on the execution plan, which details exactly what steps the DBMS takes to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one query using JOINS would be quicker. Although without knowing the relationships of the tables you are querying, the size of your dataset, or where the primary keys are, it's almost impossible to say how much faster.

Why not test both scenarios out, then you'll know for sure...