# Postgresql is this 1 query or multiple?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql (and SQL in general) and my biggest concern right now is optimization.  Below I have a simple query.  However I believe that it is just one query.  However, it could also be the case that it is just 3 queries (the ones that exist new the union all).  Or it might actually be 6 queries since there are actually 6 select statements.

```
with foo as (
    select * from tableA
), bar as (
    select * from tableB
), zeta as (
    select * from tableC
)
select * from foo
union all
select * from bar
union all
select * from zeta
```

How many queries is the above query?

---

also...

The reason this question is important is because, I do not know whether I should write my query like the above or to simply just make all the queries separate.

```
select * from tableA; --query 1
select * from tableB; --query 2
select * from tableC; --query 3
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067016/join-queries-vs-multiple-queries

Comment: in psql, "explain <query>" will show you how many sequence scans, index scans, etc.  Try it against your composite query, and against the three individual queries, and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally it is one complex query (as 'complex sentence'), which contains six 'simple' queries. You do not need these `with statements` though, as in fact they do nothing. Your first query should look like this:

```
select * from tableA
union all
select * from tableB
union all
select * from tableC;
```

In this case you'll obtain one set of rows as a result. If you execute

```
select * from tableA;
select * from tableB;
select * from tableC;
```

you will have three separate sets of rows.