# Optimizing MySQL queries from command line

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I want to optimize some MySQL queries.

I'm using [knex](http://knexjs.org/#changelog) in my app to construct queries. Using `toSQL()`, I'm able to get SQL in a format like this:

```
{
   sql: 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = ?',
   bindings: [1]
}
```

My question is what's the best way to go about optimizing these queries? If I copy the sql into the command line, for use with `EXPLAIN`, I need a way to bind the parameters. How can I achieve this?

Or alternatively, are there any better tools than using the MySQL shell to examine the optimizer's query plan?

EDIT: I just ended up copying the query into a text editor and supplying all the parameter bindings manually.

Comment: With `EXPLAIN` you need to stub in your own values, or you need to run it in your app using some kind of query altering code, like `'EXPLAIN ' + query`.

Comment: Assuming id is the PK, there's not much scope to optimise the above, other than naming the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Yeah, this is not the actual query i'm looking to optimize. Real queries have a bunch of joins and subqueries, ordering functions, etc. This is just to illustrate the problem simply.

Comment: Your MySQL query is what matters if you want to optimize it, not the JS you're using to send the query.  That makes it unclear.  Here's an answer I have to a similar question, asking about whether [JOIN vs WHERE is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144454/2430549), as an example.  Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that you need to supply real values to use EXPLAIN. It's up to you to choose values that are representative of your app's workload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a small js method which does the bindings

```js
function prepareStatment(obj) {
  let i = 0;
  const sql = obj.sql.replace(/\?/g, () => JSON.stringify(obj.bindings[i++]));
  copy(sql); // works only if you run it in chromes console.
  return sql;
}

prepareStatment({
   sql: 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = ?',
   bindings: [1]
}) // will return `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = "1"`
```

**Pay attention** - this method is not safe to use in production environment