# How to handle multiple many to many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel project in which there is likely to be multiple many to many relationships but I feel like I'm going around in circles in terms of the correct use of pivots tables.

The entities are as follows:

- **Centre:** an office that is going to open soon and has information such
  as name, location, postcode, opening date
- **Task:** a task that must be completed before a centre can open, it has information such as name, department and centre type
- **Department:** a department represents a key area such as IT, Marketing, Sales etc. Each task would have a reference to a department.
- **User:** a user is a user of the system, they belong to a department and they can complete tasks.

Considerations:

- A department has users, so users would have a department_id
- A task has a department so would also have a department_id
- A centre has departments so a pivot called something like centre_department with centre_id and department_id
- *A user has tasks assigned to them but only tasks that belong to a centre*

The bottom statement is where I'm going in circles because:

- A Task is to be assigned to a Centre which is fine as you could make a table like centre_task with centre_id and task id
- A user has tasks assigned to them, however, is it okay to have a task_user table that has user_id and a centre_task_id, effectively a pivot table that uses another pivot table?

This is because a user can't be directly assigned to a task, they can only be assigned to a task within a centre as the tasks have a many to many relationship with centres.

If I were to assign a user just using task id, they would be assigned to that task in every related centre.

So, again is it okay to have a pivot table that uses another pivot table, or does this display an issue with the structure I have suggested?

Intended flow

- A user creates a task, assigns it a department and a type so that this task is only relevant to a specific department and type of centre.
- A user can assign a task within a centre to a user who is in the department that's relevant to the department of the task
- The task in the centre would then have an assignee and a deadline

In theory I'd end up with a pivot table that has the following:

- user_id
- centre_task_id
- deadline
- date_completed

Essentially I just feel like I'm connecting too many pieces?

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, hopefully this helps! [JOIN queries vs multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144454/2430549)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does the linking for you, simply use (in this case) `morphToMany()` & `morphedByMany()` in your Models to establish a relation between two tables. There is a very good Laracast and also a very good Documentation. I have linked this below:

[Laracast Video](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) very nice Explaination for Many-To-Many Relations

[Laravel Documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=it_KKSJhM-s&list=PL3VM-unCzF8iPERY07XRw0JXG_c50CapR&index=15) for Eloquent ORM In General