# How to get collection of property in Join JPA criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to get a list of property `policy_type_id` from `ListAttribute<Article, PolicyType>`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I come up with an inefficient method was select whole Collection of `PolicyType` then filter it later

```
        Root<ArticleVersion> a = cq.from(ArticleVersion.class);
        Join<ArticleVersion, Article> join1 = a.join(ArticleVersion_.article, JoinType.INNER);
        cq.where(getCondition(cb, join1));
        cq.multiselect(join1.get(Article_.article_id), join1.get(Article_.policyTypes), a);
```

Sadly, hibernate generate an error query like this
`select article1_.article_id as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_, articlever0_.article_version_id as col_2_0_` . As you can see, there is a `.` in select that make query broken (which I believe select all)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PolicyType", schema = "SM_Request")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PolicyType {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int policy_type_id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "PolicyTypeArticle", schema = "SM_Request", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "policy_type_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching, I think that hibernate doesn't support query tuple of primitive types and list of objects (which is kinda sad, compare to LINQ to query). I decided to break down my query into smaller parts. First, I select tuples of `article_id` and `ArticleVersion`. After that, I select a list of `PolicyType` which also contains `article_id`, and union 2 lists back.

By the time I wrote this, I have an idea that I could select all 3 joins together and transform data the way I want. But It really depend on many aspects, like how many join or which type of join you're using, how fast data in each table grown ([JOIN queries vs multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067016/join-queries-vs-multiple-queries))